# Error:DatabaseError complex joins are only supported when all distributed tables are co-located and joined on their distribution columns

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to get record of related table name automation_tag but getting above error
please provide solution to solve this error
there is relation between three tables automation,automation_tag and automation_tag_relation
here is the code I am trying to do

function for getting record:-

```
export const getAutomationById = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const { branch_id, organization_id } = req.tokenData;
    const automation = await getAutomationRepo({
      where: { id, branch_id, organization_id },
      include: [
        {
          model: AutomationSteps,
          as: 'steps',
          where: { branch_id, organization_id },
          required: false,
        },
        {
          model: AutomationTag,
          as: 'automation_tag',
          where: { branch_id, organization_id },
          required: false,
          through: { attributes: ['id'] },
        },
      ],
    });

    return generalResponse(res, automation, '', 'success', false, 200);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

automation model.ts file:-

```
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'automation',
  scopes: { defaultOrganization: (organization_id: number) => ({ where: { organization_id } }) },
})
export default class Automation extends Model<AutomationAttributes, RequiredAutomationAttributesType> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  @ForeignKey(() => Organization)
  organization_id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  @ForeignKey(() => Branch)
  branch_id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(100))
  name: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING(1000))
  description?: string | null;

  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  status: boolean;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.JSONB)
  data: Record<string, any>;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;

  @DeletedAt
  deleted_at: Date;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  created_by: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  updated_by: number;

  @HasMany(() => AutomationSteps, { foreignKey: 'automation_id' })
  steps: AutomationSteps[];

  @HasMany(() => AutomationHistory, { foreignKey: 'automation_id' })
  history: AutomationHistory[];

  @HasMany(() => AutomationRevision, { foreignKey: 'automation_id' })
  timeline: AutomationRevision[];

  @HasMany(() => AutomationSetting, { foreignKey: 'automation_id' })
  automation_setting: AutomationSetting[];

  @BelongsToMany(() => AutomationTag, {
    through: { model: () => AutomationTagsRelation, unique: false },
    foreignKey: 'automation_id',
    constraints: false,
  })
  automation_tag: AutomationTag[];

  @BelongsTo(() => Branch, { constraints: false, foreignKey: 'branch_id' })
  branches: Branch;

  @BelongsTo(() => Organization, { as: 'organization', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'organization_id' })
  organization: Organization;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'creator', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'created_by' })
  creator: User;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'modifier', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'updated_by' })
  modifier: User;
}
```

automation_tag model.ts

```
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'automation_tag',
  scopes: { defaultOrganization: (organization_id: number) => ({ where: { organization_id } }) },
})
export default class AutomationTag extends Model<AutomationTagAttributes, RequiredAutomationTagAttributesType> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  @ForeignKey(() => Organization)
  organization_id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  @ForeignKey(() => Branch)
  branch_id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  color: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  created_by: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  updated_by: number;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;

  @DeletedAt
  deleted_at: Date;

  @BelongsTo(() => Branch, { constraints: false, foreignKey: 'branch_id' })
  branches: Branch;

  @BelongsTo(() => Organization, { as: 'organization', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'organization_id' })
  organization: Organization;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'creator', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'created_by' })
  creator: User;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'modifier', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'updated_by' })
  modifier: User;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Automation, {
    through: { model: () => AutomationTagsRelation, unique: false },
    foreignKey: 'tag_id',
    constraints: false,
  })
  automation: Automation[];
}
```

automation_tag_relation model.ts

```
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'automation_tags_relation',
  scopes: { defaultOrganization: (organization_id: number) => ({ where: { organization_id } }) },
})
export default class AutomationTagsRelation extends Model<
  AutomationTagsRelationAttributes,
  RequiredAutomationTagsRelationAttributesType
> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Automation)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  automation_id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => AutomationTag)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  tag_id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Organization)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  organization_id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Branch)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  branch_id: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  created_by: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @AllowNull(true)
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  updated_by: number;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at: Date;

  @DeletedAt
  deleted_at: Date;

  @BelongsTo(() => Branch, { constraints: false, foreignKey: 'branch_id' })
  branches: Branch;

  @BelongsTo(() => Organization, { as: 'organization', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'organization_id' })
  organization: Organization;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'creator', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'created_by' })
  creator: User;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, { as: 'modifier', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'updated_by' })
  modifier: User;
}
```